# Gitlab Octopus deploy integration

Tags: .net, git, gitlab, octopus-deploy

Is there a way Git lab CI can push packages to Octopus deploy? I could see open feature request https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/17598

Interested to know if this is possible.

Comment: I have [updated my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54085975/6309). Did you managed to make it work since you asked that question?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't yet available: you have another issue which illustrates the fact a usage of Octopus Deploy is done independently of GitLab:
[issues/48037: Provide Release Description from Tag in CI/CD pipeline variable](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/48037)

> I want to access the Release notes associated with a tag so that I can use them when creating a release in Octopus Deploy.
>
> Currently I can't see any way of doing this short of writing code to pull the data from the Tags API.

The [Feature Request Octopus Deploy support](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/17598) now (Oct 2020)refers to

- [`gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/lib/gitlab/ci/templates`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/tree/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates)
- [Octopus GitHub as a feed](https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/package-repositories/github-feeds) (GitHub exposes a set of APIs that allow Octopus to treat it as a feed of packages)

Answer (score 0):

Octopus has a CLI tool that is easy to script around and push artifacts from any ci tool.
https://hub.docker.com/r/octopusdeploy/octo

The better integration is for octopus to pull from gitlab.